# How to say "Knowing that I hurt you is breaking my heart"

Tags: word-choice

How does one say:

> Knowing that I hurt you (your feelings) is breaking my heart.

"Breaking my heart" I think I know:

> 胸が張り裂けています。

but the first part and how to connect the two I'm clueless about.

Answer (score 3):

I think the sentence "Knowing that I hurt you " can be translated as あなたを傷つけたと知る.

I translate your sentence as あなたを傷つけたと知り、私の胸は張り裂けそうだ.

Comment: I believe 'hurt' in the sentence is in the past tense.

Comment: Really? If so, I must change this sentence to past form but how do we distinguish their?

Comment: The verb is irregular, with all three tenses spelt the same, but parsing it as a present tense does not IMO make sense in this sentence. I'd phrase the non-past forms of 'to hurt' as _that I am hurting you_ (present) or _that I keep hurting you_ (present, repeated) or _that I will hurt you_ (future).

Answer (score 3):

あなたを傷つけたと知って、胸が張り裂けそうです。　How about this one?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a shot at my own translation for this:

> あなたを傷つけたと思うと、胸が張り裂けそう。